# Load multi delimited files in Bigquery using command-line tool

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some multi-delimited files which have to be loaded in Big query using command-line tool. This command-line interface suggests that I can use only `single-character` as a delimiter while loading a file. 
Is there any workaround which allows using combination of two or more characters as a delimiter in command-line tool?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a delimiter that doesn't appear in the data and then using a query with SPLIT (using standard SQL) to perform the processing?

Comment: I can try specifying a delimiter that doesn't appear in the data but the fact of the matter is there is no surety that the same character used as delimiter will not appear in the data in the future. So, keeping it as a futuristic approach we have decided to use combination of characters `'*|~'` as delimiter that will never appear in the source data together. Please let me know how to use the same while loading the data through BQ command line tool.